# MVC see input that caused exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

On occasion we get some robots that like to post bad information to our website (they are attempting some kind of reflection attack) but luck for us the attempts are stopped via the default input validation that one gets with MVC.

This is nice and all, but now we want to see what the robots are actually sending and we would like to log that information.  Sadly, when one gets and `HttpRequestValidationException`, the offending input is truncated to the point of being useless ala;

`A potentially dangerous.... (field = <a href=.....)`

I am trying to use an action filter to detect these exceptions, and then create a log of all of the offending input so we can see what they are trying to send.

```
public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{

    HttpRequestValidationException hex = filterContext.Exception as HttpRequestValidationException;
    if (hex == null) { return; }

    // Get the data.  This will explode throwing the same exception (`HttpRequestValidationException).  Isn't there a way that we can get our hands on the information?

    string data = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Form["field"];

....
```

This strikes me as odd and annoying because it seems that I now have no way of finding out what my attackers are really up to.  Isn't there some way that I can get the information out of the form data without getting exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the final solution that I came up with.  Works like a charm and doesn't require filesystem interaction.

```
   // Grab the contents of the request.
   Stream s = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
   byte[] data = new byte[s.Length];
   s.Read(data, 0, (int)s.Length);
   string rawData = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(data);

   // And process it into something nice and readable.
   IEnumerable<string> fields = (from x in rawData.Split('&') select  HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x));
   string formatted = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, fields);
```

Comment: Watch out, you aren't disposing the `InputStream` after you're done with it.

Comment: I don't create or own the stream so why would I dispose it?

Answer (score 5):

Yes you can. Use `HttpRequest.SaveAs` to save the entire (buffered) HTTP request to disk, which you can then read-back.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that actually invoking `Request.Form` will make the validation fire (again). I would use `Request.InputStream` directly, then. You might have to rewind the stream before reading it again:

`Request.InputStream.Position = 0`

Comment: Yeah, that's why I am using an action filter to get my hands on the exception, as seen in the code.  Your suggestion doesn't do anything to help me with the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry, read it a bit too fast. The problem is that actually invoking `Request.Form` will make the validation fire (again). I would use `Request.InputStream` directly, then.